# Audio problem rushing?

Tags: windows, hardware, audio

After using a new Pc for some time, suddendly a problem with the Audio occured.

While listening music with Headphones, some rushing noise appeared.

I tried to narrow down the problem :

- Checking the cable and connector.  (okay)
- Trying another headphone.          (rush)
- Reboot the OS.                     (rush)
- Using another Player on OS.        (rush)
- Using another extern Audio device. (no rush)
- Checking the Audio settings.       (rush)
- Running automatic Problem solving. (rush)
- Stop and restart and updating Audio drivers. (rush)
- Volume and Drivers off.             (rush)
- Monitor speakers.                   (rush)

Sometimes the rushing disappears and appears suddendly again.

Thinking and waiting to use another Sound card.

What could be the Problem ?
Maybe there is a kind of issue and simple task I oversee ?

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a reverse engineering question. It's a computer support question.